# Ubuntu 13.10 ram?

Tags: ram

Does Ubuntu  13.10 work well with an acer aspire one d255-2dqkk intel atom-n450 with **1GB** of RAM? I tried it via the installation in an usb and by booting my pc with it and it seems working well... But I want some opinions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's working well, what's the problem?

I have 24GB of RAM. Firefox has 5% of that (1.2GB) all to itself... I have other applications running at the same time too. I'd be in hell if I were on your computer.

But if you can get by, is that not enough? I don't have to suffer your computer. *You* do.

Remember that RAM is very cheap. You are again limited by your computer —it only has one slot— but you can [replace the current stick with 2GB](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=d255-2dqkk%20ram) for less than the price of two cocktails in London. You don't seem to be able to stick a 4GB stick in there (which is a shame) but still probably worth it in the long run.

Comment: Yah, thanks! I wrote "I tried via usb" because I don't know how it would work if I really install it (on the HDD, replacing Win7! :)

Comment: @Walid If you "really" installed it to your HD, then you'd have more ram available to programs, and the ability to cache ram to disk (really slow). If you don't run Firefox much (it likes eating 1-1.5GB of ram after a few tabs) then your 1GB ram might be more than enough for you. And you could dual-boot alongside win7 too

Comment: I cannot dual-boot! When trying to create a new partition from scratch, my OS (win7), let me divide the main HD only in a partition of 512MB, so I haven't got enough space for another OS...